# Oracle DBlink works for ODBC but not for OLEDB

Tags: oracle, odbc, oledb, dblink, heterogeneous-services

I´m trying to connect to an OLEDB data source using an oracle dblink, I am able to create the dblink, but I get error ORA-28545

```
SQL> select * from dual@hsoledb;
select * from dual@hsoledb
...............................*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-28545: error diagnosed by Net8 when connecting to an agent
Unable to retrieve text of NETWORK/NCR message 65535
ORA-02063: preceding 2 lines from HSOLEDB
```

On the same oracle server (10g) I have a dblink to an ODBC DSN (this one is working without problems)

```
SQL> select * from dual@HOJACONTA;
D
-
X
```

I added entries to tnsnames, listener (`PROGRAM = hsolesql`) for the OLEDB link, created an initfile (inithsoledb) and installed ODAC, but it is not working.

Does OLEDB dblinks require additional configuration or software?, do I need to install the oracle client also?

Thanks in advance for your help